# Change app configuration remotely

Tags: iphone, objective-c

We have to change some value at the app after a certain date (that can be changed) .
We want to be able to set that value remotely .
The only thing i need is to read one word from the net which says `lock` or `unlock`.
I guess i can just put some `.txt` file on the net, and read from that url with :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:some link on the net.txt"];
NSError* error;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

and set some `NSUserdefault` at the start, to read that .

so, my question , is there a site or a service that can hold that single value for me ?
i am little bit scared to put it on my url as i dont know if it can handle that amount of people .

What does devs usually do with their apps to update stuff ? and what happen if site not responding ?

Thanks .

Comment: Any site could do it - dropbox?

Comment: Actually dropbox is limited to number of reads a day, that is a secret-exactly for that matter .

Comment: OK, run your own server then.  I would argue that your question is "changing app config remotely".

Comment: parse seems great but new service, can i count on them ? its going to be tens of thousands reads in a matter of hours ..

Comment: @Curnelious you can make your own server, service and URL for that